# ubuntu 16.04 install raspberry pi3 B

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 model B instead of Ubuntu mate? If you have more information please let me know !

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi | https://askubuntu.com/questions/829643/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/972250 | (no offense: you should learn how to use a search engine, they are really useful)

Comment: user830486, I disagree with the downvote on your question. It feels punitive and undeserved. We know you have a problem and would like to help but are unable to do so because you have asked a question easily found by Google and have not asked what else you might need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50555/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-raspberry-pi-3) - perhaps see also [What is the difference between Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu MATE? Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83673/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-16-04-lts-and-ubuntu-mate-can-i-install-u) where the OP asks how 16.04 can be installed on a Pi 3.

Answer (score -1):

this answer assumes that you have already searched for and found instructions for:

```
installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 model B
```

It also assumes that the problem you are actually trying to solve is to install a different operation system while preserving information on an existing operating system. If this is indeed your situation, I would recommend that you use a new SD card for Ubuntu 16.04 in order to preserve whatever you have on your current Ubuntu Mate installation. Then plug your  SD cards into a desktop/laptop to transfer files by hand.

Comment: So is that a yes or a no.......?  This seems like more of a comment then an answer.

Comment: The problem seemed to be OP not knowing how to search

Comment: Agreed, and there is a nice comment related to that above, even includes links...  3 hours before your 'answer'

Comment: What I didn't like about the preceding comment was that it felt punitive and derogatory to the OP. I was attempting to support the OP in a helpful manner consistent with the forum. I dislike downvotes because they are generally punitive and not productive

Comment: Agreed as well, sounds like another good comment, still not an answer.

Comment: I've added a comment and left this answer as is, since the discussion is actually helpful in a meta way. Thank you.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to point the OP in the right direction, but we discourage comments and answers just giving the OP search terms without actually giving an answer. The goal of this site is to be a repository of questions — the Wikipedia of Raspberry Pi, if you will — so answers are expected to stand on their own without just pointing somewhere else. The rationale for this is largely the same as a ['link-only answer'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/336144); perhaps you could [edit] to include the relevant bits in your post.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics Aurora0001's comment sums up clearly why you have received a downvote. However, you are more than welcome to edit your answer to improve it, in which case it would attract upvotes and might be marked as correct by the OP. Since you are new to the site I recommend taking the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and looking through the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Thank you all for your patience and fine comments. I've edited my proposed answer.